# css border styling for div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with right and bottom borders, but while applying the border color to right it looks incomplete(kind of breakage) because of the given html style. Is there any css trick or any work around to override the right border will flow across in a nice way?

```
.tb{
border-right:1px solid #ccc;
border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
width:70px;
height:18px;
zoom:250%;
}
.bd{
border-right-color:red;   
}

<div>
<div style="float: left;"> 
    <div class="tb"> </div>
    <div class="tb bd"> </div>
    <div class="tb bd"> </div>
    <div class="tb bd"> </div>
    <div class="tb bd"> </div>
    <div class="tb"> </div>
    <div class="tb"> </div>
</div>
<div style="float: left;"> 
    <div class="tb"> </div>
    <div class="tb bd"> </div>
    <div class="tb bd"> </div>
    <div class="tb bd"> </div>
    <div class="tb bd"> </div>
    <div class="tb"> </div>     
    <div class="tb"> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

check the below link,

http://jsfiddle.net/gq7dc4rd/2/

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking (at least for me), could you explain better?

Comment: How do you expect this to look?

Comment: @chiapa, In DIV i have a bottom and right borders, i have added a extra class in it the right border will appear in different color. If you closely look at the each right border, you can see a small gap because of the bottom border color will differ here. But based on my sample i need a continuous flow of right side border red.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add margin-bottom: -1px to .bd However it's not the best practise, but should help.

```
.bd {
  margin-bottom:-1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uoo5utbv/

Comment: thanks for your comment. Yes its works, is there any other option other than margin. Just curious to know.

Comment: You're welcome. Another option here is to use tables instead of divs (yeah I know they suck) - so for example, in your case th and tfoot cells won't have the red border, but others will.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the way borders are rendered by most Browsers. You can work around this by using fake borders as I did using `::after` in my example: http://jsfiddle.net/maryisdead/mtwcee03/

```css
.tb{
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    width:70px;
    height:18px;
    zoom:250%;
    position: relative;
    padding-right:1px;
}
.tb::after{
    background:#ccc;
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    width:1px;
}
.bd::after{
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<p style="font:12px lucida grande">
    <b>Note:</b> I have a div with right and bottom borders, but while applying the border color to right it looks incomplete(kind of breakage) because of the given html style, Is there any css trick or any work around to override the right border will stretch across in a nice way?
</p>
<div>
    <div style="float: left;"> 
        <div class="tb"> </div>
        <div class="tb bd"> </div>
        <div class="tb bd"> </div>
        <div class="tb bd"> </div>
        <div class="tb bd"> </div>
        <div class="tb"> </div>
        <div class="tb"> </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;"> 
        <div class="tb"> </div>
        <div class="tb bd"> </div>
        <div class="tb bd"> </div>
        <div class="tb bd"> </div>
        <div class="tb bd"> </div>
        <div class="tb"> </div>     
        <div class="tb"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the right border to "flow in a nice way", you can apply a class to the containing `divs` like so:

HTML

```
<p style="font:12px lucida grande">
    <b>Note:</b> I have a div with right and bottom borders, but while applying the border color to right it looks incomplete(kind of breakage) because of the given html style, Is there any css trick or any work around to override the right border will stretch across in a nice way?
</p>
<div>
    <div class="border" style="float: left;"> 
        <div class="tb"> </div>
        <div class="tb bd"> </div>
        <div class="tb bd"> </div>
        <div class="tb bd"> </div>
        <div class="tb bd"> </div>
        <div class="tb"> </div>
        <div class="tb"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border" style="float: left;"> 
        <div class="tb"> </div>
        <div class="tb bd"> </div>
        <div class="tb bd"> </div>
        <div class="tb bd"> </div>
        <div class="tb bd"> </div>
        <div class="tb"> </div>     
        <div class="tb"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tb{

    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    width:70px;
    height:18px;
    zoom:250%;
}

.border{
    border-right:1px solid red;
    }
```

Check the new [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gq7dc4rd/3/).

Answer (score 0):

A way to do that by adding margin-bottom

```
     .bd 
   {
      margin-bottom:-1px;
   }
```